# Java Create tree with unique node ids using Primefaces TreeNode

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, treenode

I have searched for something similar, but unfortunately I did not find anything related to my problem.

So I try to create a tree dynamically with the primefaces TreeNode class (org.primefaces.model.TreeNode)

The problem is, I cannot figure out how to implement the algorithm correctly, so I can create all nodes even if the ID is a unique ID.

Entity I use:

- id (unique, Integer)
- parentId (Pointing to an id, Integer) can be null. (Then it is under root)
- name (The actual node name, String)

This is how I currently create the tree:

```
    public TreeNode createTree() {

    TreeNode root = new CheckboxTreeNode("root", null);

    List<Entity> entities = dao.getEntities();

    if (entities != null) {

        Map<Integer, TreeNode> treeNodeMap = new HashMap<Integer, TreeNode>(); 

        for (Entity entity : entities) {
            treeNodeMap.put(entity.getId(), new CheckboxTreeNode(Entity));
        }

        Set<Integer> ids = treeNodeMap.keySet();

        for (Integer id : ids) {    

            TreeNode node = treeNodeMap.get(id);
            Entity temp = (Entity) node.getData();

            if(temp.getParentId() == null) { 
                node = new CheckboxTreeNode(temp, root); 
            } 
            else {
                TreeNode parentNode = treeNodeMap.get(temp.getParentId());
                node = new CheckboxTreeNode(temp, parentNode);
            }
            treeNodeMap.put(temp.getId(), node);
        }
    }
    else {
        //TODO
        //Exception handling
    }
    return root;
}
```

This code works fine, but as I tried to mention, it does not cover the problem with the unique ID. It will not add the node if the ID of this node is bigger then the next ID in the iteration.

I want this dummy:

```
public List<Entity> dummyData() {
    List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();

    /*
     * Constructor of Entity:
     * ID
     * Parent ID
     * Name
     * */

    entities.add(new Entity(1, null, "01"));
        entities.add(new Entity(5, 1, "01-01"));
        entities.add(new Entity(108, 1, "01-02"));
        entities.add(new Entity(3, 1, "01-03"));

    entities.add(new Entity(2, null, "02"));
        entities.add(new Entity(6, 2, "02-01"));
        entities.add(new Entity(7, 2, "02-02"));
            entities.add(new Entity(77, 7, "02-02-01"));
            entities.add(new Entity(66, 7, "02-02-02"));
                entities.add(new Entity(22, 66, "02-02-02-01"));
                entities.add(new Entity(57, 66, "02-02-02-02"));
                entities.add(new Entity(180, 66, "02-02-02-03"));
            entities.add(new Entity(107, 7, "02-02-03"));
        entities.add(new Entity(8, 2, "02-03"));

    return entities;
}
```

To result in:

```
01
----01-01
----01-02
----01-03
02
----02-01
----02-02
    ----02-02-01
    ----02-02-02
        ----02-02-02-01
        ----02-02-02-02
        ----02-02-02-03
    ----02-02-03
----02-03
```

But instead it results in:

```
01
----01-03
----01-01
----01-02
02
----02-01
----02-02
    ----02-02-02
    ----02-02-01
        ----02-02-02-03
        ----02-02-02-02 <- MISSING
        ----02-02-02-03 <- MISSING
    ----02-02-03
----02-03
```

Are there any suggestions on how this problem could be solved?

Comment: you show example where node IDs are all unique, and all nodes are displayed (but in different order). So how this example is related to the question?

Comment: I just edited my question. I hope it is clearer to you now.